# prevent bottom sheet from closing because of navigator.pop

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a main page with a bunch of icons,[main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqOeQ.png), when I press them I want to navigate into another page where all the songs are listed, and if I click one of them a bottom sheet appear.[song list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xusk1.png).

So far so good, but when I try to go back in the main page with `navigator.pop` ***it first close my bottom sheet*** and if I press another one time the button it brings me back in the main page.
So, ***how can I avoid the bottom sheet to be closed and go back to the main page instead***?

Comment: Please provide the code of the page where you use your bottomsheet so people can help you.

Comment: @GuillaumeRoux this is the code of the page where alle the songs are listed: https://github.com/astroxd/sputofy_mobile/blob/main/sputofy_2/lib/playlistScreen.dart, this is the code of the bottom sheet that appears after hitting one song: https://github.com/astroxd/sputofy_mobile/blob/main/sputofy_2/lib/miniPlayer.dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `WillPopScope` widget:

```dart
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    if(isPopAllowed){
      return true; // allows pop
    }
    return false; // prevents pop
  }
  child: Scaffold(...),
);
```

Comment: so shall I just wrap my bottom sheet with this widget?

Comment: Yes. This widget also helps to show a dialog to ask about the user really wants pop.